# how can I know the current i2c speed?

Tags: i2c

I could not find this information anywhere. Where can I find the current i2c speed? It's not in dmesg, and in /sys/module/i2c_bcm2835/parameters/ I only have a file called "debug".

Comment: Does the answer help you? If so please accept it. This will finish your question and it will not pop up again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Pi's I2C bus defaults to 100 kbps.

It may be changed by the `i2c_baudrate` setting in `/boot/config.txt`.

Those are the settings used by the Linux driver.